# How to call IVsBuildableProjectCfg.StartBuild in extension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I called IVsBuildableProjectCfg.StartBuild in a Visual Studio extension to build a project.

```csharp
var ret= cfg.StartBuild(pane, VSConstants.VS_BUILDABLEPROJECTCFGOPTS_REBUILD);
```

But it doesn't start building. Instead it just produced exceptions.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The operation cannot be completed because BeginBuild has not yet been called.'
```

How can it be called correctly?

#### background

Originally I called IVsSolutionBuildManager2.StartUpdateProjectConfigurations, but when projects are configured not to be built in Configuration Manager in a solution, StartUpdateProjectConfigurations doesn't build them.

Of course this is ideal behavior because IVsSolutionBuildManager is based on solution configurations including Configuration Manager.

But even in such a case, I want to build specific projects. Actually some of the extension users wanted that and I also think it's useful.
https://github.com/Wakusei/BuildStartProject/issues/2

Comment: Please check whether [this document](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/issues/5255) does help.

Comment: Thanks, but that document is about MSBuild or I overlooked something?